# How do I perform computations over grouped data by accessing a particular column of the grouped data and then convert it back to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform some data analysis on vehicle data and need to  group the data by the vehicle ids and then based on each of those ids , use the first row for each vehicle to find the distance_along_path and subtract it with another column and then do the cumulative sum of the data.

Basically the steps for a single vehicle id are :

**code**

```
df_signal_group = df_broadway[
    df_broadway.trajectory_signal_group == '4']
df_signal_group_1 = df_signal_group[
    df_signal_group.temporaryId == 26]
df_signal_group_1['distance_along_path_change'] = (
    df_signal_group_1['distance_along_path'] - 172.78
) # this is the first row for each vehicle's distance_to_stopbar
df_signal_group_1['groupbydistance'] = (
    df_signal_group_1
    .distance_along_path_change
    .eq(-172.78).cumsum()
)
```

I have multiple such vehicles and I read to repeat these steps for all the vehicle id's

```
df_signal_group = df_broadway[
    df_broadway.trajectory_signal_group == '4']
df_grouped = df_signal_group.groupby('temporaryId')
```

I'm stuck at this step as too how do I procceed further ...
I know that I can get the first row value for every group using `df_signal_group.groupby('temporaryId').first()` ...but how to I use this data to iterate over the group for each group ...
Any pointers would be helpful.

Sample date below

[image]

This is just a samnple data in relality the vehicle ids are mixed up and hence needs grouping.

```
temporaryId trajectory_signal_group distance_to_stopbar distance_along_path onmap_status
26  4   172.78  0   True
26  4   170.33  2.459140924298365   True
26  4   167.88  4.883816339797585   True
26  4   165.49  7.274043647721051   True
26  4   164.31  8.456244827531695   True
26  4   161.96  10.794833648650943  True
26  4   159.66  13.099019997543072  True
26  4   158.51  14.238218211441483  True
125 4   173.54  0   True
125 4   172.4   1.179344296415053   True
125 4   170.01  3.5609045873593734  True
125 4   167.61  5.95965979143056    True
125 4   165.2   8.362024854827855   True
125 4   162.79  10.76439000598294   True
125 4   160.38  13.166755196815991  True
125 4   157.98  15.56912041000858   True
125 4   156.77  16.77030301927281   True
125 4   155.57  17.971485632809344  True
125 4   154.36  19.172668245991783  True
125 4   151.96  21.57503347794954   True
125 4   150.76  22.776216095592986  True
125 4   148.34  25.17858133262119   True
125 4   147.14  26.37976395246835   True
125 4   144.73  28.783361992012317  True
125 4   143.52  29.989240517622683  True
125 4   141.09  32.41716300616539   True
```

Thank you.

Expected output -

```
temporaryId trajectory_signal_group distance_to_stopbar distance_along_path onmap_status    distance_along_path_change  groupbydistance
260 4   172.6   0   True    -172.6  0
260 4   171.65  0.9526235800176956  True    -171.6473764199823  0
260 4   169.7   2.8877960903921576  True    -169.71220390960784 0
260 4   167.73  4.862869066444613   True    -167.7371309335554  0
260 4   166.72  5.865368230445712   True    -166.73463176955428 0
260 4   164.68  7.899986028468888   True    -164.70001397153112 0
260 4   163.65  8.930637572963427   True    -163.66936242703656 0
260 4   162.61  9.968169381978832   True    -162.63183061802116 0
260 4   161.56  11.011111474828203  True    -161.5888885251718  0
260 4   159.46  13.108045032255115  True    -159.49195496774487 0
26  4   172.78  0   True    -172.78 1
26  4   170.33  2.459140924298365   True    -170.32085907570163 1
26  4   167.88  4.883816339797585   True    -167.8961836602024  1
26  4   165.49  7.274043647721051   True    -165.50595635227896 1
26  4   164.31  8.456244827531695   True    -164.3237551724683  1
26  4   161.96  10.794833648650945  True    -161.98516635134905 1
26  4   159.66  13.099019997543072  True    -159.68098000245692 1
26  4   158.51  14.238218211441483  True    -158.54178178855852 1
26  4   156.26  16.490836950069347  True    -156.28916304993066 1
26  4   154.03  18.70910216437552   True    -154.0708978356245  1
26  4   151.84  20.893034435436896  True    -151.8869655645631  1
26  4   150.76  21.972132321013312  True    -150.8078676789867  1
```

Comment: mate, don't [upload images as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5847854).

Comment: oh,I am sorry about that.

Comment: I added the expected output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow of the process is to find the first row grouped by id and group columns. Next, the cumulative sum is taken to determine the order. We add the 'distance_to_stopbar' multiplied by -1 for the calculation. Concatenate the new data frame with the original one. Fill the resulting NA forward. Finally, we calculate the 'distance_alog_path_change'.

```
df_groups = df_broadway.groupby(['temporaryId','trajectory_signal_group']).first().reset_index()
df_groups['groupbydistance'] = df_groups['onmap_status'].cumsum()
df_groups['distance_along_path'] = df_groups['distance_to_stopbar'] * -1
df_broadway = df_broadway.merge(df_groups, on=['temporaryId','trajectory_signal_group','distance_to_stopbar'], how='outer')
df_broadway.columns = ['temporaryId', 'trajectory_signal_group', 'distance_to_stopbar', 'distance_along_path', 'onmap_status', 'tmp', 'distance_along_path_change', 'groupbydistance']
df_broadway.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df_broadway['distance_along_path_change'] = df_broadway['distance_to_stopbar'] + df_broadway['tmp']
df_broadway.drop('tmp', axis=1, inplace=True)

df_broadway.head(10)
    temporaryId trajectory_signal_group distance_to_stopbar distance_along_path onmap_status    distance_along_path_change  groupbydistance
0   26  4   172.78  0.000000    True    0.00    1.0
1   26  4   170.33  2.459141    True    -2.45   1.0
2   26  4   167.88  4.883816    True    -4.90   1.0
3   26  4   165.49  7.274044    True    -7.29   1.0
4   26  4   164.31  8.456245    True    -8.47   1.0
5   26  4   161.96  10.794834   True    -10.82  1.0
6   26  4   159.66  13.099020   True    -13.12  1.0
7   26  4   158.51  14.238218   True    -14.27  1.0
8   125 4   173.54  0.000000    True    0.00    2.0
9   125 4   172.40  1.179344    True    -1.14   2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I have an additional column time_stamp in the original dataset and tried follow the same steps  just added the time_stamp field under df_broad.columns (step 5) biut its giving me the column mismatch error .df_broadway.columns = ['time_stamp', temporaryId', 'trajectory_signal_group', 'distance_to_stopbar', 'distance_along_path', 'onmap_status', 'tmp', 'distance_along_path_change', 'groupbydistance'].                                   Any ided what how to resolve this ? Thank you so much again

Comment: With the new columns, I wonder if the affected code could be accomplished by modifying only the rows that are renaming the whole thing, as your comment suggests.

Comment: I was able to add the additional column. Thank you

Comment: I am having another issue with multiplying with -1 ...its giving me blank fields when I do the step 3 ... so the distance_along_path is blank and hence distance_along_path_change is non negative for me ... where I expect it to be negative ...I am wondering how you managed to do this .. its the exact same data... if you have any suggestions for this please let me know thank you

Comment: I think we can deal with this by setting the blank column to `df['tmp']=0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220123/discussion-between-shruti-and-r-beginners).